# Testing Lists Results

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am creating a Unit Testing using NLog and NSubstitute.

I have in API Controller this method:

```
    public GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem> GetYears(int startingYear = 0,  int rangeYears = 50, int startIndex = 0, int itemCount = 4)
    {
        if (startingYear == 0)
        {
            startingYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        }

        List<CalendarYearItem> years = Enumerable.Range(startingYear, rangeYears).Select(x => new CalendarYearItem(x++)).ToList();
        if (years != null)
        {
            int firstIndex = 0;
            int totalCount = years.Count;
            years = PaginateList(years, startIndex, itemCount, totalCount, firstIndex);
            return new GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem>(years, firstIndex, totalCount);
        }
        return new GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem>();
    }
```

And this interface:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Years
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List Months</returns>
    GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem> GetYears(int startingYear, int rangeYears, int startIndex = 0, int itemCount = 4);
```

I need test when call this method if return a total count 50;
If the starting year is 0 validate if first position is 2018;

```
   [Test]
    [TestCase(0, 50)]
    public void GetYears_GetCalendarListYearWithEmptyYear_ReturnCalendarListYearsStartingCurrentYear(int startingYear, int rangeYears)
    {
        GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem> calendar = new GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem>();

        _substitute.GetYears(startingYear, rangeYears);

        Assert.That(calendar.TotalCount, Is.EqualTo(50));
        //var result = _substitute.GetFullDate(year, month, day).Returns(calendar);
        //Assert.AreEqual(calendar, result);
    }
```

**Instead Assert i Need to use Collections Assert?
but when a create the arrange i have to copy my linq query to create?**

Comment: sorry o forget the test i try to write

Comment: Supposing you are using MicrosoftTest you can use CollectionAssert

Comment: When I create the calendar object i need to do this "List<CalendarYearItem> years = Enumerable.Range(startingYear, rangeYears).Select(x => new CalendarYearItem(x++)).ToList();" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunit supports collection assert. However, your question is not clear for me. What do you actualy want to test?

If you want to test your implementation returns 50 elements, you shouldn't use a mock but an object of your implementation, otherwise you are writing a test for nsubstitute. If you are trying to test the implementation of your list generator, I would expect a test like this.

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase(0, 50)]
    public void GetYears_GetCalendarListYearWithEmptyYear_ReturnCalendarListYearsStartingCurrentYear(int startingYear, int rangeYears)
    {
        var sut = new InstanceOfYourCalculator();

        GenericListItems<CalendarYearItem> calendar = sut.GetYears(startingYear, rangeYears);

        Assert.That(calendar, Has.Count.EqualTo(rangeYears));

        var expectedResult = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, rangeYears).Select(x => new CalendarYearItem(x++)).ToList();
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, calendar);
    }
```

You said you are using NSubtsitute and in my opinion, you are creating a mock which returns an empty list. On top you are not using your mock in your test, you are just initializing it. If this is not clear for you, please take a look at the tutorial of nsubstitute.
http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/

Comment: " in my opinion, you are creating a mock which returns an empty list" that's not an opinion - it's either a fact, or a false statement :)